# Explaining transistor schematic

Tags: transistors, phototransistor

I have been away of Electronics Engineering since 2008, it seems I missed a lot of basic concepts. I came across this schematic:

[image: schematic]

I found a weird wiring, the capacitor that is tied to VCC, should be open circuit at DC frequencies, how the transistor is going to be fed by VCC in that case? I suppose that the correct wiring is to tie the resistor to the VCC and take filter the output by that capacitor in parallel.

Comment: It seems very strange to me as well...

Comment: Huh?  There is no capacitor anywhere in your circuit.  I see a opto isolator, two resistors, and a connector.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams from this very question, I swear. Anyhow, it's different now.

Comment: The schematic has now changed again.  This mess needs to be closed.  We can't tell what is being asked about anymore.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: He's asking about [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9454).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I just clicked the link, and that's what came up...

Comment: Sorry for posting a wrong link! A new link is updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The device in question is meant to be used with a bidirectional digital pin. Setting the pin to a high output discharges the capacitor, resetting the circuit. Realize that the capacitor "discharges" high and "charges" low since it is tied to VCC rather than ground.

In order to make a measurement, the pin is switched to an input. When the transistor is triggered, the capacitor charges low at a speed governed by how activated the transistor is via the reflection of the diode off a surface. Since the software *knows* when it changed the output to an input and it can detect *when* the input goes low, it can use this timing to sense how reflective the surface is.